# Creating sequence generator by batch script in .csv file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have the following code for merging .csv files into a single csv file

```
@echo off
SET SUMMARY_FILE=D:\sumfile.csv
IF EXIST "%SUMMARY_FILE%" (DEL "%SUMMARY_FILE%")
CD D:\Prasad
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %f IN (`DIR /S /B *.csv`) DO (
    TYPE "%f" >>"%SUMMARY_FILE%"
)
```

The problem is that after merging I need to generate a new column with numbers starting from `1` to `n` where `n` is the number of rows in merged file:

```
1
2
3
4
.
.
.
.
.
.
n
```

Comment: `for /F "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%g in ('findstr /N "^" "%SUMMARY_FILE%"') do echo %%g %%h` could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution with `>>` opens and closes target file on each iteration. Next solution with `>` redirection accomplishes the job at once:

```
@echo off
SET "SUMMARY_FILE=D:\sumfile.csv"
rem not necessary IF EXIST "%SUMMARY_FILE%" (DEL "%SUMMARY_FILE%")
pushd D:\Prasad

> "%SUMMARY_FILE%" (
for /F "tokens=1,2,* delims=:" %%g in ('
  findstr /S "^" "*.csv" 2^>NUL ^| findstr /N "^"
  ') do if not "%%i"=="" echo %%g,%%i
)
```

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`>>`, `2>NUL` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just read and write each line of the file with a line number at the beginning. Also, in .bat files the FOR loop variables must have double percent characters.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET SUMMARY_FILE=D:\sumfile.csv
IF EXIST "%SUMMARY_FILE%" (DEL "%SUMMARY_FILE%")
CD D:\Prasad
SET /A LINE_NUMBER=1
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`DIR /S /B *.csv`) DO (
    FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%s IN (`TYPE "%%~f"`) DO
        ECHO>>"%SUMMARY_FILE%" !LINE_NUMBER!,%%s
        SET /A LINE_NUMBER=!LINE_NUMBER!+1
    )
)
```

Comment: It is neither merging nor producing LINE_NUMBER with numbers... If possible can u pls re check the script... Even last time i have received the similar script from u...

Comment: I did find one backtick that I missed. In what way is it "not working?" Is there and error message? What comes out in the `%SUMMARY_FILE%`?